# Is there a way of mainpulating the zero flag in gdb?

Tags: x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

i want to reverse engineer an executable and in process i want to cause a stack overflow, because of the strcpy function. When disassembling there is a  jne after a compare and when is false code continues to an exit function and as a result exiting the program.If it is true it jumps and goes to a custom function, where the strcpy is used.I was thinking that i have to manipulate the zero flag to avoid calling the exit function.Is my thought correct and if so is there a technique in gdb to use? Thank you in the process

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is about x86.  You can set the EFLAGS register (which contains ZF) using:

```
(gdb) set $eflags = 0
```

This will clear all bits that can actually be cleared, including the ZF bit.  If you just want to clear the ZF flag, you can use the fact that its bit has value 0x40:

```
(gdb) set $eflags = $eflags & ~0x40
```

`info reg eflags` shows the effect of such manipulations.

Comment: Thank you very much that was really helpfull